# Effecting the environment flag from within the build

Tags: aurelia

I have an Aurelia CLI app that uses the CLI in conjunction with Gulp to build. I was asked to enable a feature where we pass the name of the branch we're building and determine an environment from that. I was hoping to do this within my gulp tasks. I think I can achieve it through our Continuous Integration, but, I'd like to do it from within gulp if possible. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use Visual Studio Team Services for Continuous Integration. I added a Powershell Script build step to our definition, which, depending on the name of the passed branch, would write a variable with the right environment name. Then, I'm planning to add an additional build step to my definition, to only run when the master branch is being built - to rebuild my source without the testing framework.

The powershell script we use to write the variables is as follows:

```
if ($env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME -eq "qa"){
 Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=auenv]" + "stage")
}
elseif ($env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME -eq "master")
{    
 Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=auenv]" + "prod")
}
else
{
 Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=auenv]" + "dev")
}
```

Then, when it comes time to use it:

```
au build --env $(auenv) --version $(Build.BuildNumber) --testable
```

Finally, we build without the test framework

```
au build --env $(auenv) --version $(Build.BuildNumber)
```

I recognize my solution is out of scope relative to the audience I asked it for. Sorry about that.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing your final solution :)

Comment: @Travis Brown If your solution worked for you, it's ok to mark it as the answer. This helps other people find it.

Comment: @kettch will do - I just have to [wait 22 hours to do so](https://www.screencast.com/t/fClHUl5HvV) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any custom arguments to Aurelia CLI and grab them from within your build tasks.

Say you call `au run --branch master`

You can get the value from within a task like so:

`import { CLIOptions } from "aurelia-cli";`

`const branch = CLIOptions.getFlagValue('branch')`

Is that what you need?

Comment: It's not, but, I found a different way to do it. I will add a main comment with my solution. Appreciate your answer all the same, as this partially factors in to what I ended up doing as well.